# ListView item remains checked after setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I am implementing `ActionMode.Callback` and some `ListView` stuff. My problem is that when I am in choice mode `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and I check some items, then I can't clear selections.

I am trying to do it like that:

```
getListView().clearChoices();
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
```

But selected items still remains selected. This is my whole implementation:

```
private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback
{
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        actionMode = mode;
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_cab_menu, menu);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        return true;
    }


    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }


    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        getListView().clearChoices();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
        actionModeCallback = null;
        actionMode = null;

    }
};
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that changing the mode is supposed to clear your selections, and I wouldn't try to change selection modes once set either... seems like a bad idea.

Rather than doing that, why not use the method made to clear a list of choices such as [clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29)?

Simple example:

```
ListView lv = getListView(); 
lv.clearChoices();
```